# How to add a tracking parameter to Google +1 button, to track click-backs

Tags: google-plus-one

I have some information about the visitor on my page that I would like to attach to the URL of the page so that when it's Liked to Facebook or +1'd to Google, and someone clicks back through that link, I can track that. For Facebook, "ref" parameter does exactly what I need - the link goes to the wall of the sharer as http://example.com/?fb_ref=MYVALUE. Is there a way to do the same with +1 button?

If I'll just add a parameter myself, Google will consider http://example.com/?g_ref=far a different page from http://example.com/?g_ref=bar.

I tried adding a hash parameter like this: http://example.com/#g_ref=far - this kinda works, but only for the title of the story. On the sharer's wall, the title will link to correct URL (with the hash param), but if someone clicks on the story thumbnail, it goes to the URL with hash param stripped out (which is weird, but true).

So is there a way to mark the shared URL somehow to track click-backs from Google Plus?

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer to this? As far as I can tell, it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also visualize activity on Google+ for a particular URL is by viewing the ripples.

Visit https://plus.google.com/ripple/details and enter your URL.